# Update jQuery version in Shopware 6

Tags: jquery, shopware, shopware6, storefront

A project I'm working needs a third party javascript snippet which has a dependency on the 'full' jQuery framework. Shopware (/bootstrap 4) currently ships with jQuery out of the box, but is using the Slim (and not full) version of it.

Is there a way to upgrade/change the used jQuery version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to actually replace the slim jQuery with the full version.

In `MyPlugin/src/Resources/app/storefront/build/webpack.config.js` put the following:

```
const path = require('path');
const projectRootPath = process.env.PROJECT_ROOT
    ? path.resolve(process.env.PROJECT_ROOT)
    : path.resolve('../../../../../../../');

const shopwarePlatformPath = projectRootPath + '/vendor/shopware/platform/';
const nodeModulesPlatformPath = shopwarePlatformPath + '/src/Storefront/Resources/app/storefront/node_modules/';

const shopwarePath = projectRootPath + '/vendor/shopware/';
const nodeModulesPath = shopwarePath + '/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/node_modules/';

let webpack = null;
let fullPath = null;
try {
  require.resolve("webpack");
  webpack = require('webpack');
} catch (e) {
  try {
    require.resolve(nodeModulesPlatformPath + "/webpack");
    webpack = require(nodeModulesPlatformPath + '/webpack');
    fullPath = nodeModulesPlatformPath;
  } catch (e) {
    require.resolve(nodeModulesPath + "/webpack");
    webpack = require(nodeModulesPath + '/webpack');
    fullPath = nodeModulesPath;
  }
}

let webpackConfig = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      /jquery\.slim/,
      fullPath + 'jquery/dist/jquery'
    ),
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      /jquery\/dist\/jquery\.slim/,
      fullPath + 'jquery/dist/jquery'
    ),
  ],
};
module.exports = function () { return webpackConfig };
```

Answer (score 4):

In your plugin create a `webpack.config.js` the directory structure should look something like this:

```
├── MyPlugin
│   └── src
│       └── Resources
│           └── app
│               └── storefront
│                   ├── build
│                   │   └── webpack.config.js
│                   └── src
│                       └── main.js
```

The content of `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const { join, resolve } = require('path');

module.exports = () => {
    return {
        resolve: {
           alias: {
               '@jqueryNew': resolve(
                   join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'jquery'),
               ),
           },
        },
    };
};
```

Then within the `storefront` directory install the latest version of jquery or whatever specific version you need:

```bash
npm install jquery
```

In your `main.js` you can then import the newer jquery package from the resolved alias and set it globally:

```js
import $ from '@jqueryNew';

window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```

Comment: Thanks @dneustadt! I was almost there, but trying to remove the jquery-slim from the core in my `webpack.config.js` file. Didn't get any luck there. Overriding the $ and jQuery globals seems to be a great solution! (Too bad the jQuery.slim still gets loaded by core Shopware but oh well... That will not be an issue anymore after 6.5.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

Small additional information:

If you change the webpack.config.js in ypour plugin make sure to build the frontend afterwards:

`bin/build-storefront.sh`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will be removed with the next major. It's not future-proof to still use it. You should look for alternatives, it's not so complicated with default javascript

Comment: I agree. I think I haven't properly used jQuery myself for the last 3 or 4 years. But the 3th party service the client uses does not want to upgrade their code so we're stuck with it.